# MySQL PHP SELECT WHERE id equals largest

Tags: php, mysql

Does anyone know how to do this in PHP?

```
SELECT (values, stuff) FROM database WHERE id = <Largest>
```

My table contains the columns `ID`, `Code`, `Other`, etc.  I need to get the last/latest entry in the database (i.e. where the `id` is the largest).  The ID is the key.

For example, in a table such as:

```
1, abc, ...
2, ghc, ...
```

It should return `ghc`.

Comment: Order by DESC limit 1, will always return you latest interted id,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order them desc, then select the first one

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.

**1) Use of `ORDER BY ID DESC` + `LIMIT 1`**

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

`ORDER BY ID DESC` will sort your records in descending order, according to the id attribute.

`LIMIT 1` will return you one (and the first) record.

Thus, returning you the record of the largest id in your table.

**References:** [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp), [LIMIT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

**2) Use of sub-query + `MAX`**

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table);

First, `(SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)` will retrieve the largest id in your table.

Next, this largest id will be used in `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id =` to retrieve its record.

Thus, returning you the record of the largest id in your table.

**References:** [Subquery](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php), [MAX](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp)

**Examples:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88518/1

Comment: I have no idea too. I even provided explanation for the solutions ._.

Comment: the second one is not optimized.

Comment: @kosturko I didn't down-vote but my guess would be redundancy. Both the answers gave in this solution where already given in previous solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to lean more about mysql queries.
[MySQL Tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm)

To get the max id you need to perform order by DESC query to get largets ID value. As your ID is primary key in the table.

```
select * from table_name order by ID desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use query to simply get the `MAX` for `id`. Because doing ordering (by `ORDER BY`) over an entire amount of records can be quite inefficient if we happen to have a lot of data, as it has to do a sort over all the data in the table. We can instead select the largest ID, then select the record that has that largest ID in the table:

```
SELECT Code FROM table WHERE ID=( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table );
```